# Print specific characters

Tags: java, string, for-loop, input, char

I have a string input which, that input have a team name and score separated by one space. e.g `bb 3` , `teamd 5` the winner should be `teamd`

In order to get the winner team that scored highest score, i'm doing following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cases = scanner.nextInt();

    printWinnerTeam(cases);



}

public static void printWinnerTeam(int cases) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = "";
    String winnerTeam = "";
    int winnerScore = 0, countedChar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        str += scanner.nextLine();
    }
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        countedChar++;
        if (arr[i] == ' ') {
            if (str.charAt(i + 1) > winnerScore) {
                winnerTeam = "";
                winnerScore = (int) str.charAt((int) i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j < countedChar; j++) {
                    winnerTeam += str.charAt(j);
                }
                countedChar = 0;
            } else {
                //winnerTeam = "";
                countedChar = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(winnerTeam);
}
```

But it's not work prefect, It's print wired result, how to make that work as expect ?

Comment: How about simplifying it but just processing as you go.  If entered lines score is biggest then store the number and the teams name - use String.split(",");

Comment: I haven't tries your code, But i would imagine a big problem is the concatenation of `str += scanner.nextLine();`  The new line is going to be appended straight onto the end of the previous lines `number`

Comment: @ScaryWombat indeed yes, i'v go thinking  outside box, my issue with `+=`, thanks, feel free to make it accept answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried your code, But I would imagine a big problem is the concatenation of `str += scanner.nextLine();` The new line is going to be appended straight onto the end of the previous lines number

Have a look at this

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String team = "Nothing entered";
    System.out.println("how many teams");
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    while (count-- > 0) {
        System.out.println("Entered team,score");

        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String arr [] = line.split(" ");
        // check size - TBD
        if (Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) > bestScore) {
            bestScore = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            team = arr[0];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("nest team is " + team + " with a score of " + bestScore);
```

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I need to clean my screen

Comment: Excuse me, do you know what's wrong [here](https://ideone.com/tB1Akw), to get runTimeError with my code?

Comment: @android works fine for me in Eclipse `how many cases
2
how many teams
2
Entered team,score
test1 2
Entered team,score
me 23
me
how many teams
2
Entered team,score
test2 4
Entered team,score
me_again 23
me_again
me
me_again
`

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do something like that I will do it like this:

```
import java.util.*;
        public class winner {
           public static void main (String args []) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int cases = scanner.nextInt();

            printWinnerTeam(cases);
        }

   public static void printWinnerTeam(int cases) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String winnerTeam = "";
            String Team="";
            int winnerScore = 0, score = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
                Team = scanner.next();
                score = scanner.nextInt();
                if(score > winnerScore){
                 winnerTeam = Team;
                 winnerScore = score;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Winner team" + winnerTeam + "Score:" + winnerScore);
        }
        }
```